# How would I add the data from this query to an array?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way that I can put the data from the while loop into an array and output it using echo? I've tried defining an array and just appending it with `.=` but it does not add.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM coils WHERE name like '%$term%' or 
                                            resistance like '%$term%' or 
                                            wraps like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_one like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_two like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_three like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_four like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_five like '%$term%' or
                                            wire_six like '%$term%' 
                                            LIMIT 25";
        $prep = $db->getConnection()->prepare($query);
        $result = $prep->execute();
        $rowCount = $prep->rowCount();

        if ($rowCount <= 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('No Results, please try another search');</script>";
        } 

        while($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<a href='coil.php?id=" . $row['uniqueid'] . "'>";
            echo "<div id='search_result'>";
            echo "<div id='search_title'>Name: " . $row['name'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div id='search_ohms'>Resistance: " . $row['resistance'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div id='search_wraps'>Wraps: " . $row['wraps'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div id='search_around'>Wrapped Around: " . $row['wrapped'] . "</div>";
            echo "<div id='search_description'>" . $row['description'] . "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</a>";
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add output in an array and then use `implode()`.

```
$temp = array();

while($row = $prep->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $temp[] = "<a href='coil.php?id=" . $row['uniqueid'] . "'>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_result'>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_title'>Name: " . $row['name'] . "</div>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_ohms'>Resistance: " . $row['resistance'] . "</div>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_wraps'>Wraps: " . $row['wraps'] . "</div>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_around'>Wrapped Around: " . $row['wrapped'] . "</div>";
    $temp[] = "<div id='search_description'>" . $row['description'] . "</div>";
    $temp[] = "</div>";
    $temp[] = "</a>";
}

echo implode(' ', $temp); //with or without space
```

Comment: Is it bad practice to output HTML from a class/PHP ?

Comment: It's better to use MVC (Model - View - Controller) pattern. Many frameworks use it (Yii framework, Laravel etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the data in an array with:

```
$data = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

To display it, you can close PHP with **?>**, then use the alternate syntax for nice clean HTML:

```
<?php foreach ($data as $row) : ?>
<a href="coil.php?id=<?= htmlentities($row['uniqueid']) ?>">
<div id='search_result'>
<div id='search_title'>Name: <?= htmlentities($row['name']) ?></div>
<div id='search_ohms'>Resistance: <?= htmlentities($row['resistance']) ?></div>
<div id='search_wraps'>Wraps: <?= htmlentities($row['wraps']) ?></div>
<div id='search_around'>Wrapped Around: <?=htmlentities($row['wrapped']) ?></div>
<div id='search_description'><?= htmlentities($row['description']) ?></div>
</div>
</a>
<?php endforeach ?>
```